How to use templates with C++ inner class
Consider the following C++ code:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
        public:
                struct InnerStruct
                {
                        T val;
                        InnerStruct(T v): val(v) {};
                };
};

template<typename T>
T get_val(std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>::InnerStruct>& p)
{
        return p->val;
}

int main()
{
        std::unique_ptr<MyClass<int>::InnerStruct> p = std::make_unique<MyClass<int>::InnerStruct>(1);
        int x = get_val(p);
        std::cout << x << std::endl; 
        p.reset(nullptr);
        return 0;
}

I've created templated class, MyClass, which has an inner structure called InnerStruct. The only template argument of MyClass, i.e. T, is used to create an object in the InnerStruct. I then create a unique pointer to the InnerStruct and call the templated function get_val on the pointer to the InnerStruct object. get_val simply reads out the value stored in the InnerStruct object and returns it. I get this value and print it out on stdout and finally delete the unique pointer to the InnerStruct object.
However, when I try to compile this, I get the following errors:
   16 | T get_val(std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>::InnerStruct>& p)
      |                                                  ^
a.cpp:16:50: note:   expected a type, got ‘MyClass<T>::InnerStruct’
a.cpp:16:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
a.cpp: In function ‘T get_val(int&)’:
a.cpp:18:17: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
   18 |         return p->val;
      |                 ^~
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:24:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_val(std::unique_ptr<MyClass<int>::InnerStruct>&)’
   24 |         int x = get_val(p);
      |                 ~~~~~~~^~~
a.cpp:16:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> T get_val(int&)’
   16 | T get_val(std::unique_ptr<MyClass<T>::InnerStruct>& p)
      |   ^~~~~~~
a.cpp:16:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:24:24: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
   24 |         int x = get_val(p);

i don't understand what note:   expected a type, got ‘MyClass<T>::InnerStruct’ means. ‘MyClass<T>::InnerStruct’ is a type of a structure but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it as such. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
Note: my question is different form this question. I'm not asking about why one needs to use typename, rather I'm struggling with a compiler error.

I've swapped the dupe to the correct target talking about the type deduction issue.  cc @Someprogrammerdude.  Your issue is that in MyClass<T>::InnerStruct T is in a non-deduced context so you have to explicitly supply T to the function.

I found the problem. The compiler was not able to determine whether MyClass<T>::InnerStruct is a value or a type. So adding typename before it to make it explicit that this represents a type fixed the problem.

Minor point: in Java, an "inner" class has some magical properties related to its "outer" class. C++ doesn't do that, and the usual term for a class that's defined inside another class is a nested class.
